# looping over webelements and getting href in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

hello i am trying to get the links of a specific keyword in Facebook pages.
i have been trying for hours but it's  not working.

let's say the input keyword is orange

the result in pages are a list of banana pages.
the code is as below:

```
 first_result = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, "(//div[@role='feed'])[1]") # getting the container of the divs

        ok1 = first_result.find_elements(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='article']")
 # trying to get each div by the css selector because using classname will only get the first element

ok = ok1.find_elements(
            By.CLASS_NAME, "aeinzg81 i15ihif8 cgu29s5g jg3vgc78 gb2oqlaf")

# the class containing the text
        for _ in ok:
            print(_.text) # i wanted the hrefs but i printed the text to see the results clearly
```

i get no results " blank"
can someone please help.
i will put a link for reference please inspect it using the inspector in the browser.

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=orange
```

i have added a couple of screenshots for further explanation.
[here1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT6dN.png)
[here2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyCz8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have added the code used and attached 2 essential photos that eases understanding

Answer (score 0):

For class names, you need to put dots between the selectors.

For example:

```
ok = ok1.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "aeinzg81 i15ihif8 cgu29s5g jg3vgc78 gb2oqlaf")
```

should be

```
ok = ok1.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "aeinzg81.i15ihif8.cgu29s5g.jg3vgc78.gb2oqlaf")
```